# Copy vertex shape key information to a different object

Tags: shape-keys

I have a face and an empty space behind the eyes (to render it in anime style), the connection between the eyes and the empty space has the same number of vertices and in the same positions, I made a shape key in the face to blink an eye, is there a way to copy the vertex information of the shape key to the empty space object?

I tried with transfer shape key but since they don't have the same number of vertex it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go like this: create a copy of the mesh with shape keys, delete all the vertices not interested by shape changes, delete the corrispondent vertices in the empty space mesh, connect the copied vertices (with the same shape keys) to the empty space mesh: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to join the two meshes, then delete double to connect the two separate parts.